# Instagram Graph API to collect the likes, comments that the user made

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm working on a web application where the user provide access to access their social media data. so, i can gather the info like their likes, comments and build a persona from their social media handles. now, i know there exists Instagram and Facebook APIs for this about which I'm confused, but I have some queries regarding the data we get.

Do we get the data such as likes and comments or its only limitted to the ones in their own posts and the likes in that.

I need some data for creating their persona. So, is this a way for doing this through the API or should I look for another way for data.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to get user likers data. Open user likes go to dev tools and analyze Network tab. However Instagram limits the data you can get up to 100 likes here it should be in `likers` in your network tab.
If you want to get almost all likers you can get it by using Instagram graphql query hash. Few years back it was available in network tab, I'm not sure where it's right now. There is no information on the web how to get it now days but some people still can get new query hashes (because Instagram changes it sometimes) I hope somebody will let us all know how to find it.

```
https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/media/{media_id}/likers/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).